# How to format integer in Spark SQL?

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I am new to Spark. Any help will be appreciated. Is there any alternative for sql's `FORMAT()` in Spark SQL. My core logic is written as SQL and running with `spark.sql("query")`. I have a requirement to convert the id to 4 digit.

For example, if if is 1, it should be converted to 0001, if it is 12, then 0012. I know in SQL, we can do it as `FORMAT("%04d", id)` as `id`. But this is giving me error in Spark SQL saying `FORMAT is not a function registered`. Found `format_number` and `format_string` in Spark's documentation, but not helping in my case.

Note: I don't want to do this in my java code, but would like to do in SQL query itself.

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/#format_string

Answer (score 1):

Use `lpad` function.

```
spark.sql("SELECT lpad('1', 4, '0')").show

+-------------+
|lpad(1, 4, 0)|
+-------------+
|         0001|
+-------------+
```

You can change `'1'` to `id`.